# How to make hour and minutes as x axis in nvd3.js graph

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using `nvd3.js` to plot a graph with `x axis` as time and `y axis` as some decimal value.
I would like to make the `x axis` as `HH:MM` but am stuck here. Is there any way to do so.

Comment: Can you post some code that you are trying.It will be easy to get helped and will be more easy to find the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a custom `tickFormat` to do this:

```
chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d));
  });
```

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. According to: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting, that second identifier represents "month" not "minute".

Comment: Oh indeed, thanks for spotting! I'll edit the answer.